# How can i do a Previous / Next from a list of id's

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok i have a list of records that i would like to make a next / previous link on the edit page that will go to the next or previous ID

I am getting a list of records from the database like this

```
@leads = Lead.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(:completed => false)

[#<Lead id: 954, name: "Matson/DLI", user_id: 1, completed: false>, 
 #<Lead id: 1454, name: "48 State Freight", user_id: 1, completed: false>, 
 #<Lead id: 1900, name: "FederalLogisticsSales",  user_id: 1, completed: false>]
```

The id's will be random.

if i have the lead # `1454` active i would like to make the links at bottom go to either `954 or 1900`

THESE will go to next and previous ID but not from my list

```
<a href="/leads/<%= @lead.id - 1 %>/edit"><--- Previous</a>

<a href="/leads/<%= @lead.id + 1 %>/edit">Next ---></a>
```

No this will not work for me... there will be 1000 + records

```
@leads.last   or    @leads.first
```

### Update to Vasseurth post

i got

```
   @leads[index]
undefined local variable or method `index' 

    @leads.class
    => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

so i did this

```
leads = []
    leads << @leads
    leads.class
    => Array

    leads[index]
undefined local variable or method `index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that command and generated response, `@leads` looks like an array. That means that you can index it via `@leads[index]`. Perhaps having your link, link to `@leads[index+1]` for next or `@leads[index-1]` for previous will accomplish what you are trying to do. (Of course you will have to make sure that you cannot click previous on the first entry or next on the last).

Another point, definitely make use of the rails `link_to` tag. Your way of going about linking seems a little off (though not necessarily wrong). Somelinke like:

```
<%= link_to 'Next', edit_lead_path(@leads[index+1]) %>
<%= link_to 'Previous', edit_lead_path(@leads[index-1]) %>
```

Will create the same link but in a "rails" way.

Let me know how it turns out.

To clarify:

The first method (without the `<<`) is correct, you just haven't defined `index` yet.
I assume you are displaying this on the leads `show` page. So you have to define and correctly set `index`.

Comment: index needs to be the index value of the current record

Comment: How can i get the index of current record?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, index was simple supposed to be a variable representing the index of the array. I.e. @leads[1] will be the first entry, so @leads[2] will be the second (next) entry and so on. You have to define `index` and as whatever number you want to start at.

Answer (score 0):

While on the edit page, you have the id of the lead currently being edited, let's say it's 1454, so `params[:id] = 1454`.

In the edit method of the controller, you could have something like:

```
@next_lead = Lead.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(:completed => false).where("id > ?",params[:id]).first
@previous_lead = Lead.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(:completed => false).where("id < ?",params[:id]).last
```

Probably not the most efficient but it would work.